# Proof for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $a_{n} = \frac{2n+1}{n+1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The sequence ${a_{n}}$ converges to 2. Give a value $N$ such that $|a_{n}-2|<0.1$ for all $n\ge N$. Give a value $M$ such that $|a_{n}-2|<0.01$ for all $n\ge M$.

Can someone help me figure it out either for $N$ or $M$? 
Thank you!

Comment: Just plug the definition of $a_n$ into the inequality and solve it.  Note that $a_n \lt 2$, so the inside of the absolute value sign is negative, so your inequality is $2-a_n \lt 0.1$

Comment: So $2-\frac{2n+1}{n+1} <0.1$, I just solve for n and that will be my $N$?

Comment: That is correct.  You have to convince yourself that the inequality stays true for all larger $n$.  In this case it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that  $$a_{n} = \frac{2n+1}{n+1}$$

$$a_{n} = \frac{2n+2-1}{n+1}$$

$$a_{n} = 2-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Therefore for all $n \in \mathbb N ,$$$a_{n} <2$$

Thus $$|a_n-2|=2-a_n$$

That is for the first part , $$2-a_n <0.1$$

$$2-a_{n} =\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{10}$$

$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{10}$$

$$n+1>10$$

$$n>9$$

That is whenever you choose an integer which is greater than $9$ you can have that $|a_n-1|<0.1$. So pick $N=10$